# I want to make a new installation to my Unity Hub. What happens to the modules?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Just want to make sure that I'm going to do the right thing. Am I right that when I download a new installation to unity hub, I am to delete the old versions which I don't use?
If that's correct, how do I do it? Will I need to download all the modules again?

Comment: Every Unity Install lives in a separated folder. You can safely delete the entire folder of an install in order to uninstall it. So yes every Unity install requires its own modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you won't be needing the old Unity version, no worries, you can safely uninstall it.

And yep, you'll need to install all the modules again. Their content might change for the new version which you are going to install